# Testing builtin `contrib.auth.login` with a Client.get() request

Tags: django, authentication, pytest

My goal : accessing the `loging` URL with *Test Client* with posting `username`/`password` to log a user in.

I use built-in `contrib.auth.login` in *Django* 2.1.4

test.py :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import auth
from django.test import Client
from django.urls import reverse

def test_login_valid():
    U = {'username': 'bob','password': 'bobbobbob'}
    u = User.objects.create(**U)
    C = Client()
    r = C.post(reverse('login'), U)
    su = auth.get_user(r.wsgi_request)

    print(u)
    print(r)
    print(su)
    print(su.is_authenticated)
    print(r.wsgi_request.user)
    print(r.wsgi_request.user.is_authenticated)
```

Running test:

```
pytest --capture=no a14n/tests.py::test_login_valid
(…)
bob
<TemplateResponse status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8">
AnonymousUser
False
AnonymousUser
False
.
```

registration/login.html:

```
<form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

urls.py:

```
from a14n import views as a14n_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', a14n_views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

On the other hand in a *Django shell* it works perfect :

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> from django.test import Client
>>> from django.contrib import auth
>>> from django.urls import reverse
>>> U = {'username': 'bob','password': 'bobbobbob'}
>>> C = Client()
>>> r = C.post(reverse('login'), U)
>>> u = User.objects.create(**U)
>>> su = auth.get_user(r.wsgi_request)
>>> print(u)
bob
>>> print(r)
<HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/accounts/profile/">
>>> print(su)
bob
>>> print(r.wsgi_request.user)
bob
>>> print(r.wsgi_request.user.is_authenticated)
True
>>> print(su.is_authenticated)
True
```

Why tests gives ma a `TemplateResponse` object and *django shell* a `HttpResponseRedirect` in response?

Anyway, redirected or not, why tests cannot log the user in?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution!

In my test I use `u = User.objects.create(**U)` which creates a `user` with a clear password, then my view can never authenticate because `login()` expects a hashed password.

With `u = User.objects.create_user(**U)`, password for *test user* is hashed and test is working.

Hope it will help someone :-)